# jQuery .html does not show element name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a form which contains some input and combo-boxes. Base on JQuery UI dialog a user can change the name or some other attributes of the form element:

```
var targetEl = $('input[name="input_box_1"]'); //assume selected input name is "input_box_1"
targetEl.prop('name', $('#new_name').val());
```

This works fine so that if I change the name to something else and reselect the element it shows up the new name.
The problem is that I want to get whole form's outerHTML after these changes, when I alert or print the whole form by using `$('#my_custom_form').html()` it shows all other changes for the inputs and combo-boxes except for their name.

This is what comes from `alert($('#my_custom_form').html());`

```
<TABLE>
<TR>
<TD><LABEL id=new_id_set name="new_name_set">Name:</LABEL></TD>
<TD><INPUT id=input_box_newID value= class="cstm_font1"></TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
```

What I expect to be is

```
<TABLE>
<TR>
<TD><LABEL id=new_id_set name="new_name_set">Name:</LABEL></TD>
<TD><INPUT id=input_box_newID name="input_box_newName" value= class="cstm_font1"></TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
```

Does anybody know how to get full outerHTML with the input names, either through jQuery or JavaScirpt?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you have no inputs with `name='input_box_1'` so `$('input[name="input_box_1"]')` will select nothing - using prop works fine here [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9fMr6/)

Comment: another thing is - you are missing quotes around your id's

Comment: @ᾠῗᵲᄐᶌ I have that input, as I said it's just example. Imagine first time the input name is `input_box_1` then the user change the name to `input_box_newID` through the interface by `$('input[name="input_box_1"]').prop('name', 'input_box_newID');` this works fine but it does not affect on the element's outerHTML

Comment: can you make a fiddle of your code?  Maybe you're missing something here

Comment: Here's another example - this is what you're talking about right? http://jsfiddle.net/m8QVP/  The name seems to change just fine in the elements

Comment: @ᾠῗᵲᄐᶌ Yes you and all other guys answer are correct, but does it work for dynamic elements, too? I mean if the form elements are created dynamically will it work? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
targetEl.attr('name', $('#new_name').val());
```

Then

```
alert($('#my_custom_form').html());
```

EDIT:

http://jsfiddle.net/duq23/

[From jQuery Docs:](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop-propertyName-functionindex--oldPropertyValue)

"Properties generally affect the dynamic state of a DOM element without changing the serialized HTML attribute. Examples include the value property of input elements, the disabled property of inputs and buttons, or the checked property of a checkbox. The .prop() method should be used to set disabled and checked instead of the .attr() method. The .val() method should be used for getting and setting value."

Comment: `attr` is deprecated in jQuery new version; I used `prop` instead, it works, means it changes the name correctly but it does not affect on the element's outerHTML

Comment: @Javad where does it say that `.attr()` is deprecated?

Comment: @ᾠῗᵲᄐᶌ Sorry not deprecated but in the documentation it's mentioned **To retrieve and change DOM properties use `.prop()`**

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like:

```
$('#input_box_newID').attr('name');
```

Javascript approach would be:

```
var inputs, index;

inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (index = 0; index < inputs.length; ++index) {
     var input = inputs[index];
/*
    input.value gives you the value
    input.id gives you the id
    input.name gives you the name
*/

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: As you know `attr` is deprecated in new version of jQuery and we can use `prop` instead; however I used `attr` by using jQuery Migrate plugin, too; but still have the issue. It seems it change the name correctly but it does not effect the outerHTML

Comment: Sorry not deprecated but it's suggested to use `prop()` to change any DOM properties